# System.Net.SocketException because of not connected Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I'm new in Socket programming. I try to write an C# chat. Every time when i call this function:

```
    void starteServer()
    {
        try { 
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress localIpAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localendpoint = new IPEndPoint(localIpAddress, serverPort);

            server.Bind(localendpoint);
            server.Listen(10);
            Recive(server);

            lb_chat.Items.Add(response);
            receiveDone.WaitOne(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorHandler(e);
        }
    }
```

i get an System.Net.SocketException with the reason of an unconnected Socket.  I think i breaks in the Recive(server)-line. This is the Recive Method:

```
    private static void Recive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObjeckt state = new StateObjeckt();
            state.workSocket = client;
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObjeckt.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorHandler(e);
        }
    }
    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObjeckt state = (StateObjeckt)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObjeckt.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
```

hopefully someone can explain me this behavior and help me fix it.

if you need the rest of the code just visit:
https://gist.github.com/chrishennig/ea4b5a974fc6f9aa2bb6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to read data from a listening socket, like it is the socket that is receiving data. When you [Listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen(v=vs.110).aspx) with a socket, it is only used for calling [Accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept(v=vs.110).aspx) to accept connections, and then those subsequent connected sockets are then read and written to. So, the exception is telling you that you are trying to read from a socket that isn't connected anywhere, which is correct since no sockets have yet been accepted.